# Problems in starting mysql server

Tags: linux, fedora, mysql, fedora-12, selinux

I'm trying to start the mysql server on fedora 12. `service mysqld start` gives me an error:

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting MySQL:                                        [FAILED]
```

More details

```
[root@localhost mysql]# which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql


[root@localhost mysql]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.46, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

And also I get a weird pop in the notification area regarding some security threat

`SELINUX is preventing /usr/libexec/mysqld "read" access on plugin.frm`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like SELinux is preventing MySQL from reading the database files. Try:

```
restorecon -rF /var/lib/mysql
```

which will ensure the contexts are set properly on the database files.

Also have a look in `/var/log/mysqld.log` to see if there are any useful messages.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Richard Fearn's answer, which correctly diagnoses the problem (+1 for that), the following:

If it is a server/development environment, you might consider disabling SELinux entirely, since it's more of a burden than it does good. On a normal desktop, I'd recommend against doing that though.

I suggest you read the following carefully if you're thinking about disabling it.: http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html